# Notification of updated file in database on android app

Tags: android, mysql, jakarta-ee, android-notifications

I am developing an Android app in which i need to add one feature in which if there is any new file added by server in Mysql database it should notify on android app. What should I do for this?
 please help.
 Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lot of solutions to resolve your demand.

**1 Implementing push notifications**
Whenever a new file added, send a notification to your app with the download link so your app can download the appropriate file.

**2 Implementing a background service (consume more battery)**
This service will check if there is a new file on server side every X times (for example 1 day)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be via push messages. The standard way to do this on Android is via Google Cloud Messaging: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I haven't ever tried it, but it seems like what you need is offered by Google Cloud Messaging.
(http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html)

It should let you push notifications to your Android App whenever you have uploaded a new file.